# Word request: person from a different company that supplies people/services

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a person from a different company that supplies people/services for you to use constantly?

Comment: Please provide some context and/or examples of people who fit the bill.

Comment: I think this is often called a "personnel service".  Though "temp agency" is a more colloquial term (that the services like to avoid using).

Answer (score 1):

It's simply "supplier". That's the universally used word.

Answer (score 0):

The first word that comes to my mind is **contractor** which according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contractor) and [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/contractor) seems to fit.

Note however that this term is very broad simply designing *someone who has entered a contract* (legal or a natural persons alike) while in its narrower meaning it appears to be primarly used for construction firms.

Comment: It's not just used in construction. In high tech, we often hire contractors in lieu of permanent employees.

Comment: A **contractor** is a particular type, a subset, of supplier.  The answer to the OP is very simply "supplier" - a term used constantly in business.